# How does ASP.NET detect browser capabilites?

Tags: asp.net, httpwebrequest

Today, during some other somehow related work, came across my mind the following question: How does ASP.NET detect browser capabilities? Is seems it can not from request header, as the `this.Request.ServerVariables["ALL_RAW"]` should reveal all request headers, but there is nothing about browser capabilities in there? They obviously are somewhere else. Where? How to get those raw data?

**For clarification:** this is not a question about how to get browser capabilities from ASP.NET. This one is simple (`this.Request.Browser`, here you can find all).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ASP.Net includes [`.browser` files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228122.aspx) that map `User-Agents` to capabilities.

Comment: That's some really good documentation from MSDN -- thanks for the link.

Comment: Ok, that is interesting. I have also think about that, but it does not fit me, because that implementation is *leaky*. This only mean, that this is not actually representation of user browser state. It just represent just a browser capability (as name rightly suggest) and nothing more. So you as a developer you can just assume that user can use JS (without client sidecode help, of course).